# Automate button click when it appears - Chrome/Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, css, jscript

First time post.

So i've had a look at a few different examples by people on here as to how to go about this but i'm really struggling to accomplish what i'm after.

I have a webpage that I use in my job which is a monitoring tool. I log into every morning, however after about 30 minutes (give or take), a countdown timer appears along with an 'extend' button which allows me to extend the active session by 30 minutes, at which point the cycle continues.

I've managed to get the system to browse to the page and login with my credentials automatically using iMacros, however I can't seem to get the extend button to auto click when it appears. I've looked at Tampermonkey which I think gives me what i'm after, but writing JScript, well i'm a complete amateur!

Does anyone know a method in which I can auto click this button when it appears using Tampermonkey? I'm guessing a "setinterval" method, but i'm really struggling to go about this. Any help would be appreciated.

I believe the below is the code for the button and countdown timer:

```html
<div class="alert alert-block popup-alert-notice" dynamic="true" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1503303727269_312">
"Warning! Due to inactivity, your session will expire in "
<span class="countdown-timer" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1503303727269_314">00:00:40</span>
". To extent your session another 30 minute(s), please press the "
<em>Extend</em>
"button."
<button class="btn submit popup-alert-close">Extend</button> == $0
</div>
```

Comment: if i were you i would write a chrome extension for it, as with extensions you can manipulate the DOM -> click buttons when they appear, for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, if the button is removed once it is clicked.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("btn submit popup-alert-close");

  elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(elements);

   if(!elements.length) return;
  elements.forEach(function(btn) {
     btn.click();
  });
}, 200);
```

Comment: Hi bluehipy, thank you, this works fine if I run it through the console in chrome manually, however in tampermonkey as a userscript, i'm getting an error stating: "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression." which is stopping me from saving the script and having it run consistently. it seems to be between:      btn && btn.click && btn.click(); });

Comment: I have updated the script. Let me know if it solved the issue :)

Comment: I still have the same error on the script, but now only after the closing bracket on the line beneath button.click(); - so the }); on line 8 if you will.

Comment: Ok, rewritten the old ways :)